# Create Same Size Image Across Various Android Densities

Tags: android, android-layout, image-manipulation, android-image

My goal is to create 6 images of different densities that are the same size across the 6 generalized Android screen densities.

From reading Android's documentation  on supporting [multiple screen sizes](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#overview) I understand the dpi unit (dots per inch) really represents physical pixels per inch.

In my understanding, this means an image that is 160 pixels by 320 pixels on a 160 dpi screen will show up the same as an image that is 640 pixels by 1280 pixels on a 640 dpi screen.  And both images will appear to be *about* 1 inch by 2 inches on their respective screen configurations. Is my understanding correct here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add images of various dimensions in various drawable folder viz- drawable-ldpi,drawable-mdpi and so on.
And the image dimension ratio will be:
Taking mdpi as a base 
your ldpi will be 0.75 times of mdpi
hdpi - 1.5 times of mdpi
xhdpi - 2 times of mdpi
xxhdpi - 3 times of mdpi 
as mentioned in the link
http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#overview under alternative drawable section

Comment: This makes sense.  So if I have an image that I want to show up as (1 in. X 2 in.) dimensions then the pixels dimensions for the images will be (120 pixels X 240 pixels) for the ldpi folder, (160 X 320) for the mdpi folder, (240 X 480 pixels) for the hdpi folder, and so on?